# How can I intercept a link with jQuery when using a ajax call?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I might be doing something stupid.  But if I have a normal link like:

```
<div id="changeMe"></div>
<a href="/Not/Intercepted" id="interceptMe">A link</a>
```

and I attach a jQuery click event to the link like so:

```
$('#interceptMe').click(function() {
  $('#changeMe').text('Changed');
  return false;
});
```

Everything works peachy.  The page does **not** get redirected to /Not/Intercepted, which is what I would think would be correct.

Now...

I introduct a ajax call like $.get to my click event and now my page will be incorrectly redirected to the page, which essentially overwrites the ajax call.

```
$('#interceptMe').click(function() {
  $.get('/Ajax/Call', goesIn, function(comesOut) {
  $('#changeMe').html(comesOut);
    }, "html");
  return false;
});
```

Is there a way to make jQuery or javascript still intercept the link click so it does not go to the href page?  I want to keep the href for those users that aren't enabling javascript.  TIA!

Comment: Are you sure that doesn't work? Because it looks OK to me (ie it shouldn't redirect).

Comment: That's what I was thinking.  It looks correct to me too, so not sure what the heck is going on.

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674991/intercept-click-event-on-a-button-ask-for-confirmation-then-proceed/4675010#4675010

Answer (score 24, accepted):

instead of return false, use ....

```
$("#interceptMe").click(function(event){

    event.preventDefault();

    // Ajax here

    return false; //for good measure
});
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event#event.preventDefault.28.29

I've had many issues with IE especially not listening to return false. Apparently so have others http://coffeeandpaste.blogspot.com/2009/02/javascript-onclick-return-false-does.html

Comment: @rball 'return false' should do the same thing though. I have never had this problem before in 3.5 years of using jQuery. If 'event.preventDefault' works and 'return false' doesn't, please let me know.

Comment: Will do, thanks for the response.  I also thought it was odd, but it's happening on everything I have a ajax call on.

Comment: @KyleFarris I've had many issues with browsers not working with return false. preventDefault() works so far 100% so I have switched to it for more reliable code. I updated my answer with a link to others having the same issue.