# Page redirecting after setting the ajax response to div

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc

Page is redirecting to a new page(view) even though i set the view response(AJAX Call) to a div class on the same page. Ajax call was successful and i could see the response in console.

**home.jsp:**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Gen</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">   </script>
<spring:url value="/resources/css/gen.css" var="mainCss" />
<spring:url value="/resources/js/gen.js" var="mainJs" />

<link href="${mainCss}" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="${mainJs}"></script>

</head>
<body id="layout">
  <div id="header">
   <h1>XYZ</h1>  
 </div>
 <div id="top-nav">  
   <ul id="top-nav-list">
     <li class="top-nav-list-item" id="gen">
        <a class="top-nav-links" id="requestui" href="getrequestui">Generate</a>
    </li>   
 </ul>
 </div>
 <div id="container">
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

**gen.js**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){    

    $('#requestui').on('click',function(){
        var urlBuild = '/gen/getrequestui';
        $.ajax({
            url: urlBuild,
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            success: function (response) {
                $("#container").html(response);
            },
        });

    });     

});
```

Comment: See here: You need to prevent the default action. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648916/jquery-capture-anchor-href-onclick-and-submit-asynchronously and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/788463/how-can-i-intercept-a-link-with-jquery-when-using-a-ajax-call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
<a class="top-nav-links" id="requestui" href="getrequestui">Generate</a>
```

with

```
<a class="top-nav-links" id="requestui" href="#">Generate</a>
```

Comment: You have provided url in the href attribute so, when clicking the hyperlink its redirecting to the new page.

Comment: Incorrect.  Questioner needs to prevent the default action on click regardless of the href.